# Laplace Inequality

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy, probabilistic-encryption, probability

I am trying to prove that if $r_i \sim Lap(0,1/\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon >0$ then:

$$Pr[r_i \geq 1+r^*]  \geq e^{-\varepsilon}Pr[r_i \geq r^{*}]$$.

I know that for $r*>0$ it satisfies with equality. Even though, for $r <0$, I couldn't find out how to prove it.

Note $Lap \sim (\mu,b)$:

$$Pr[X \geq x]  = 1-F(x)=\begin{cases} 1-\frac{1}{2}\exp(\frac{x-\mu}{b}) && \text{if }x< \mu \\ \frac{1}{2}\exp(-\frac{x-\mu}{b}) &&\text{if } x\geq \mu\end{cases},$$

Comment: Your equation is incomplete. What is $1/\epsilon$? The spread parameter? Unless the negative case is $-1\leq r* <0,$ such an inequality won't hold since the distribution is of the form $c \exp(-|r|)$ thus it is increasing for $r\leq 0.$

Comment: I think what its happening is the contrary. When $r* <-1$ the inequality holds. I did some calculations and works very well. When $-1\leq r* <0$, is more complex because when $1+r*>0$, the cumulative distribution may change for some values $1+r*$ and $r*$. This inequality is from proof of Report Noisy Max in differential privacy.

Comment: well i hadnt seen your full equation. by the way your $x\geq \mu$ case is still looks wrong. The distribution is *negative*

Comment: Yeap, it's positive. If you maybe take some time thinking about it and find a way to solve it, will help me a lot !. Yeah, I just changed it to seem more clearly in the question. I have spent like two days already :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I did this quickly. Hope it’s correct.

When $r*\geq 0,$ the relationship holds as you observed. And when $r^*\leq -1,$ the same expression for both probabilities you want to compare enables a direct proof.

Let $r^*\in(-1,0),$ so that $1+r^* \in (0,1).$ Then what you want to show is
$$\frac{1}{2} e^{-\epsilon(1+r^*)}\geq e^{-\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{\epsilon r^*}\right)
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{2} e^{-\epsilon(r^*+1)}+
\frac{1}{2} e^{\epsilon (r^*-1)} \geq e^{-\epsilon}
$$
or
$$
e^{-\epsilon} 
\left(
\frac{ e^{-\epsilon r^*}+ e^{\epsilon r^*}}{2} 
\right)\geq e^{-\epsilon}
$$
which holds since the cosh function is lower bounded by $1.$

---

When $r*<-1$, a litlle more larger, we want to find the next inequality:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    e^{\epsilon} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon(x+1)} \right) \geq  1-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon(x)}\\
    e^{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon x+ 2\epsilon}\geq  1-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon(x)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Which we will bounded by both inequalities using the fact that $r*\leq-1$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    r* &\leq -1\\
    e^{\epsilon r*} &\leq e^{-\epsilon}\\
    e^{\epsilon x + 2\epsilon} &\leq e^{\epsilon}\\
    -\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon r*+ 2\epsilon} &\geq -\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon}\\
    e^{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon r*+ 2\epsilon} &\geq e^{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The same way we have:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    r* &\leq -1\\
    1-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon x} & \geq 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\epsilon}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Joining this inequalitys, we can obtain

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    e^{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}e^{\epsilon} > 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\epsilon}\\
    2(e^{\epsilon}-1) > e^{\epsilon}-e^{-\epsilon}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Where the inequalitie holds since $2>1$ and $-1 \leq - e^{-\epsilon}$

Comment: That proof seems correct ! But can you show also when $r* \leq -1$ ? I don't see the direct way.

Comment: Already did the proof of $r*<-1$, it's not so direct. Anyway thanks, for the tip :)

Comment: Been too busy with a deadline. Feel free to edit answer to include that case..

Comment: Perfect, done. I think its correct